# Use Spotify API in Python to play song on device without the user logging in?

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I'm creating a program to play music on my Amazon Echo. I just want a script that- given a track's URI- will start playing it on my device.

I've been using the [Spotipy](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io) library to do this. However, I'm running into an issue.
When I set my credentials using SpotifyClientCredentials:

```
spotify = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret))
```

I get an error that `Player command failed: Premium required, reason: PREMIUM_REQUIRED`.

After doing some research, it seems I need to use OAuth to login and do this since the device is specific to my account.

So, I have this code to do that:

```
spotify = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(client_id=client_id,
                                                    client_secret=client_secret,
                                                    redirect_uri='https://localhost:8080/',
                                                    scope='user-library-read'))
```

However, even when I do that my browser doesn't give any key in the URL, and the window just says `INVALID_CLIENT: Invalid redirect URI`.

Additionally, this is part of a larger script that will read a Spotify URL from an NFC tag and start playing the song. I don't want to have to manually login or have the user do anything manual once the program is created.

Since this isn't a public web app and is just for me, is there any way to have a script like this that just plays the song given the client id/secret or user login info? And if not, what redirect URI can I put so this works?

I'm just playing the song by:

```
spotify.start_playback(device_id=echo_id, uris=[test_track_uri])
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out I just had to add the callback URI to the Spotify settings and it all worked. It also saved the credentials so I only had to login once.

Comment: If you feel that this is the correct answer, you can mark it as correctly answered, so that it can help others in future.

Comment: i am also looking for a way to play music on Alexa Automatically using a Script. is that even possible?